# Installing GCC For Free?

Tags: root-access, ssh

I have a rooted android device I want to use as a toy server. I need to install GCC, so I can ssh in and compile other software.

How do I install GCC and whatever libs/headers I need to compile command-line binaries, without buying one of the commercial solutions like C4droid?

Comment: What GCC has to do with a rooted device? Plus, GCC **is** [freeware](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/). There is also a Debian chroot for Android, [Lil Debi](https://guardianproject.info/code/lildebi/).

Comment: Can you deploy GCC binaries on an unrooted device? Wouldn't they then be restricted to executing in the context of the app that installed them? I don't really know.

The GCC install instructions require a number of things (for example, a working C++ compiler) that preclude me building it on my device. And I'm not sure what cross-compiling options I would pass to the GCC build system to induce it to create an Android ARM build--hence my asking the question.

I'd like to install just GCC, without an entire Debian system. The Debian chroot would get GCC, though.